# Vim: Error format matches everything

Tags: vim, errorformat

I am trying to match the following error with [`efm`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#errorformat):

```
AssertionError: 1 == 2
    at /home/strager/projects/blah/blah.js:13:37
```

The error message can be anything (i.e. it doesn't always match the `AssertionError: .*` or `.*Error: .*` formats).  The general format is:

```
errormessage
    at filename:line:column
```

My problem is that the error message matches *any* line; I need to restrict the error message to one line only, and only match if it's followed by a matching "at" line.

I have tried the following `efm`:

```
set efm=%Z\ \ \ \ at\ %f:%l:%c,%E%m
" %Z    at %f:%l:%c,%E%m
```

This almost works, but it matches status lines (e.g. non-errors before and after the error) in addition to the errors.  How can I force `%E%m ... %Z` to be only two lines total (one for the error message, and one for the `at` line)?  I have access to the standard UNIX tools for `makeprg` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to spend your time learning an obscure pattern language that has no application anywhere else?  Unless someone is paying you to write vim compiler plug-ins, I wouldn't (and I love vim!).  Since you're willing to open the toolbox, just write a wrapper around your checker and spit out an easy-to-parse format.  Eg:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, '-|', 'compiler', @_ or die $!;

my $last_line = <$fh> // exit;
while (defined(my $line = <$fh>)) {
    my($file, $l, $c) = $line =~ /^    at (.+?):(\d+):(\d+)$/;
    print "$file:$l:$c: $last_line" if defined($file);
    $last_line = $line;
}
```

Comment: How to use this perl script in vim?

Comment: Just `:set makeprg=...`.  That is, whatever program you were using as `makeprg`, just replace it with this script.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of replacing `-w` with `use warnings;`. The `-w` switch is pretty much only needed for compatibility with perl 5.5, which didn't support lexical warnings, but your script requires 5.6 anyway because of the `open` syntax used. (Actually it requires 5.10+ because of `//`.)

Comment: Your code only works if `compiler` writes error messages to stdout, not stderr.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
set efm=%Z\ \ \ \ at\ %f:%l:%c,%E%m,%-G%.%#
```

The %-G%.%# tells vim to ignore entire lines that do not match the other patterns.

Answer (score 0):

What about ...

```
set efm=%E%m,%Z\ \ \ \ at\ %f:%l:%c
```

Comment: This is what I had initially, but this matches every line as an "error" with no more information.  The `efm` I posted in my question does this but also detects the file name and line and column numbers of the "at" line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
set efm=%E%>%m,%Z\ \ \ \ at\ %f:%l:%c
```

Check this

```
:help efm%>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.